# Window title with renderUI()

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to have a changeable window title in my shiny app based on user selection. While there is no problem with main title and other parts of app, I'm struggling with window title.

I tried use `renderUI()` and `uiOutput()` but without any success.

```
# packages
library("shiny")
library("shinyWidgets")

# app
runApp(list(
  # UI  
  ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
    # title panel
    tagList(div(div(style = "display: inline-block; ",
                    h1(uiOutput("uiMainTitle")), class = "main_title"),
                div(style = "width: 65px; display: inline-block; float: right; ",
                    pickerInput(inputId = "color",
                                label = " ",
                                choices = c("blue", "red")))),
            tags$title(uiOutput("uiWindowTitle")))
    )),
  # SERVER
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    # main title
    output$uiMainTitle <- renderUI({
      ifelse(input$color == "blue", "Blue title", "Red title")})
    # window title
    output$uiWindowTitle <- renderUI({
      ifelse(input$color == "blue", "Blue app", "Red app")})
    }
  )
)
```

Any suggestions are warmly welcomed.

Comment: Where do you want the window title to be placed, Window title you mean the tab title?

Comment: Yes, I mean title in browser tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use shinyjs package and some js code. This solve the problem:

```
# packages
library("shiny")
library("shinyWidgets")
library("shinyjs")

# app
runApp(list(
  # UI  
  ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    # title panel
    tagList(div(div(style = "display: inline-block; ",
                    h1(uiOutput("uiMainTitle")), class = "main_title"),
                div(style = "width: 65px; display: inline-block; float: right; ",
                    pickerInput(inputId = "color",
                                label = " ",
                                choices = c("blue", "red")))),
            tags$title("blue")
  ))),
  # SERVER
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    # main title
    output$uiMainTitle <- renderUI({
      ifelse(input$color == "blue", "Blue title", "Red title")})
    # window title
    # output$uiWindowTitle <- renderUI({
    #   ifelse(input$color == "blue", "Blue app", "Red app")})

    observeEvent(input$color,{
      #in the place of input$color you can put your personal title
      titlejs=paste0("document.title ='", input$color,"'")
      runjs(titlejs)
    })
  }
)
)
```